# Not able to get menu items on navigation drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I am trying to add a navigation drawer to my app. So, My navigation drawer is opening and closing perfectly, but there is no menu items visible on navigation drawer This is how main xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawableLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/customToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <LinearLayout...> //This linear layout has all the elements of UI.

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is how my menu items looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item android:id="@+id/homeMenu"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_menu_icon"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/signUpMenu"
        android:title="Sign Up"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_signup" />

    <item android:id="@+id/loginMenu"
        android:title="Login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_open" />


</menu>
```

And this how my main activity looks like

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        actionBarDrawerToggle =    ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawableLayout,customToolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        drawableLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle!!)
        actionBarDrawerToggle!!.syncState()

        setSupportActionBar(customToolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.title = ""
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.homeMenu -> Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Home clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.signUpMenu -> Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "SignUP clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.loginMenu -> Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            true
        }
```

Btw I am using customToolbar theme

```
<style name="Theme.CustomToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

My navigation drawer is opening and closing perfectly, but there is no menu items visible on navigation drawer. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Try this once -

```
 val drawableLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawableLayout)
    val customToolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.customToolbar)
    val navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
    val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawableLayout,
        customToolbar,
        R.string.app_name,
        R.string.app_name
    )
    drawableLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

    setSupportActionBar(customToolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.title = " "
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.homeMenu -> Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity3,
                "Home clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            R.id.signUpMenu -> Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity3,
                "SignUP clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            R.id.loginMenu -> Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity3,
                "Login clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        true
    }
}
```